# Is there any way to replace Segoe UI emoji that comes with windows with a font that supports flag emojis in chrome?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, fonts

Emoji flags are supported on all major platforms except Windows, which displays two-letter country codes instead of emoji flag images.